# Show site in Google search

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask

I recently developed and deployed a website for a restaurant in my area.

I used HTML, CSS, JS and the Flask micro-framework.

For the domain, I bought one on GoDaddy and for hosting, I opted for a plan on PythonAnywhere.

Everything works correctly and the site seems to be online (both *site-domain.it* and *[www.site-domain.it](http://www.site-domain.it)*).

The only problem I'm facing is the following, if I search in the Google search engine (so not in the Chrome top bar) for the name of the restaurant (the one that is also in the  tag), it doesn't show up in the results the link to the website.

I did some research online and I think the solution is to "link" the website to Google Search Console.

I tried to follow the necessary steps to get everything done, I waited 2-3 days for it to be managed.

But still the website is not shown in the search results and if I search for *site:site-domain.it* it is as if it didn't find anything.

I live in Italy and for this reason my domain is .it

Could anyone help me or give me some advice on this?
Being the first time I approach this type of problem, I would like some help, so I know how to behave in the future.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing can take anywhere from a few days to a couple weeks until it's done, so it could just be, that your site has yet to be indexed.

There are a few things however you can do, to speed up the process and make sure everything gets indexed correctly:

1. Add a robots.txt file: https://www.semrush.com/blog/beginners-guide-robots-txt/
2. Make sure your robots tags are set correctly inside your `<head>` tag: `<meta name="robots" content="index,follow">`
3. Add a sitemap to your website: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/sitemaps/build-sitemap

Following article might help you as well: https://www.semrush.com/blog/google-index/

Comment: I put the robots.txt file in the static folder and if I go to the url /robots.txt it shows me the file content, but Google Search Console still doesn't detect it for me :(

Comment: In Google Search Console, in the "Indexing" section it still tells me "Wait a day or two", maybe that's why?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned above, indexing doesn't happen immediately, it will take a few days and in some cases even a few weeks. If it still doesn't work after a while make sure to double check your robots tags and the url you registered in the google search console

Comment: Okay, the website was indexed just now.
When I search for site:domain-name.it I get the website.
Only when I search for the name of the restaurant, it still doesn't show.
Do I have to wait any longer? Or do I have to do something else?

Comment: You will have to improve your SEO ranking. There are lots of articles that can help you with that, for example this one https://ahrefs.com/blog/seo-basics/